# How to view similar commands in terminal?

Tags: command-line

OS version: Ubuntu 12.04

I wrote `veditor` in my terminal and got the following message:

> No command 'veditor' found, but there are 39 similar ones

My question is how can I **view** those 39 **similar commands**?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://askubuntu.com/questions/197633/any-way-to-list-similar-commands

Comment: Seems to be same situation, and it is common in Ubuntu. e.g from my machine: `saji@geeklap:~$ veditor
No command 'veditor' found, but there are 39 similar ones
veditor: command not found`

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear what kind of editor did you mean by `veditor`?

Looks to me like a typo.
If you type in `editor` a predefined text editor will start. In my case itś Nano.

Other editors you can use are gedit, vim, vi, etc.

Even `man -k veditor` doesn't even show suggenstions.

Comment: No No, you did not get my point. I know there is no such command as veditor and i am not even interested in running an editor, i know how to do that. what i am interested is in those <b> 39 similar ones </b> . is there a way to have a look at those commands?

Answer (score 0):

for example if you know only starting of the command like vi then type vi and press tab then you will get the commands which starts from the name vi.

Comment: This is not always correct. By using the tab key- you show the possible solutions to any command starting on "vi-". That means, it might not be similar, but actually it will be exactly those two ++ more.

Answer (score 0):

The command-not-found script doesn't seem to have any way to do this by default.

Here's a modified version that takes a --all option.

https://gist.github.com/kaqualls/5447454
(click the permalink button in the top right to download the file)

```
python ./command-not-found --all veditor
```

This prints a list of every package that provides the 'editor' command.

The algorithm used to check for misspelled commands is very simple, so I doubt this will ever be helpful.

This page pointed me toward the right script:
http://linuxers.org/article/how-ubuntus-command-suggestion-feature-works