# How to show 'similar' commands when you forget the exact command

Tags: bash, gnome-terminal

If I get this:

```
No command 'pdf' found, but there are 16 similar ones
pdf: command not found
```

How do I see the 16 similar commands?

Comment: This has been asked before (although perhaps not directly answered): [Any way to list similar commands?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197633/any-way-to-list-similar-commands)

Answer (score 2):

If you know part of the command's name you could try `apropos`, e.g., in your case

```
apropos pdf
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> and start typing your command. If used it earlier it will show you. A good trick to save a lot time.

Answer (score 0):

As hinted at in this previous answer [Any way to list similar commands?](https://askubuntu.com/a/197684/178692) the way to get at them seems to be to execute the `spelling_suggestions` method from the `CommandNotFound` python module directly, and then call `print_spelling_suggestions` with a suitably large value of its `max_alt` parameter in place of the default value `15`:

```
$ python3 -c '
import sys
from CommandNotFound import CommandNotFound
cmd = sys.argv[1]
cnf = CommandNotFound.CommandNotFound()
cnf.print_spelling_suggestions(cmd,cnf.spelling_suggestions(cmd),[],100)
' pdf

Command 'pdf' not found, did you mean:

  command 'sdf' from deb sdf
  command 'puf' from deb puf
  command 'pydf' from deb pydf
  command 'pdv' from deb alliance
  command 'psf' from deb tcm
  command 'pdl' from deb pdl
  command 'xpdf' from deb xpdf
  command 'wdf' from deb wit
  command 'kdf' from deb kdf
  command 'df' from deb coreutils
  command 'pdd' from deb pdd
  command 'pda' from deb speech-tools
  command 'qpdf' from deb qpdf
  command 'p0f' from deb p0f
  command 'paf' from deb libpod-abstract-perl
  command 'pd' from deb puredata-core
  command 'pdb' from deb python

Try: sudo apt install <deb name>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the recommended cmd in your **terminal**,

I recommend this application:
https://github.com/nvbn/thefuck

You can install it by `pip3`:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3-dev python3-pip python3-setuptools
sudo pip3 install thefuck
```

And config it as you like in files like `.bashrc` for your shell:

```
eval $(thefuck --alias)
# You can use whatever you want as an alias, like for Mondays:
eval $(thefuck --alias FUCK)
```

---

Besides, commands combo like `history | grep pdf` can also work if you have executed the right command before.